# Concerns Regarding Class Redundancies Vs Performance

Tags: java, performance, frontend, backend, web-development-server

I am coding a web application-- both the front end and the back end.

I have a class called Student.

In the front end, the user is able to search for other users using their First Name, Last Name, Email, and University. However, in the back end, there are more properties that are automatically configured such as their ID, Account Age, etc and these properties do not affect the search.

The bottom line is, I was wondering if I should make a separate class such as that only contains the relevant search properties (such as first name, last name, etc) as the other properties are not relevant or if I should just keep one Student class to keep things simple.

I'm leaning towards only a single class. However, the issue I see here is that I may be affecting performance by retrieving more information than necessary. The main benefit I see of having a single class is that it would save memory and reduce code length.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stop worrying about performance  and  concentrate on good design. There are a lot of best practices related to your use case. Your search params can be wrapped around form beans or REST body, and your student can be just a DTO.

Comment: I would worry about clarity first and performance later when you have a load test which shows you have a performance issue you consider how to optimise it.